# Can you receive user info via Azure go sdk?

Tags: azure, go, sdk

I need to work with Azure services, so I use github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go but also want to get a user email. Do I have to use the graph SDK (github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go) for this?

My app allows authentication of both multi-tenant AD users and personal accounts.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to use the graph SDK
> (github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go) for this?

Yes, you would need to use msgraph-sdk-go SDK to interact with Graph API. You can find more information about using the SDK here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/sdks/sdks-overview.

Comment: sadly it seems it's impossible to use both graph (`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`) and azure (`https://management.azure.com//.default`) scopes at the same time. Azure SDK has graphrbac but it's deprecated

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: In my case I use oauth2 to authenticate azure sdk to work with azure services, when you receive a oauth2 token you should specify scopes. When you specify both graph and azure scopes you get an error about scopes being invalid. So, you can't use both graph sdk and azure sdk using the same credentials

Comment: What you cannot do is combine two different scopes (Graph API and Azure Management API) in a single token request. You will need to make two separate token requests.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used an oauth2 token to authenticate both azure and graph SDKs. It's impossible to work with both SDKs using the same token because specifying scopes for both graph `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` and azure services management `https://management.azure.com//.default` returns error about the scope being invalid.

So, you can't use Azure SDK for personal accounts, it must be a work account. Microsoft allows to have both personal and work account using the same email (and different passwords). Azure SDK does have graphrbac service that in theory can be used to fetch a user email but this service has been recently announced as deprecated.

I've ended up realizing I don't really need a user email, I'm fine with having a subscription ID.